How to save the node positions of an entity-relationship (ER) diagram in Sql Developer
I have generated an ER Diagram for a schema with lots of tables, by following this approach
After generating it, I re-positioned all the nodes (tables) in the diagram (Relational Model) so that they are grouped by the functionality they provide. This took me quite long.
What I want now is, to save the state of the diagram so that in the future, when the schema is moved to a new version, I just import the new tables without loosing the positions of the existing tables in the diagram.
I cannot find a way to do it. I right-clicked on my Design (in the Data modeler Browser view on the left) and selected Save Design. It created a directory with multiple sub-directories and files. But I do not know how to load that design again, which I suppose will contain the state of my Relational Model.

File open, recent designs...or look for the XML file having the name of your design in that root directory. I have some tutorials on my blog.

The title says "How to save...." but the final sentence of the question says "But I do not know how to load that design again". Is the problem saving or loading?

When you save your design, it ALSO saves the positioning of the entities or tables and their relationships in the digram(s).
Starting from scratch, a new design
I'll import data from my database, using HR schema
And once it's in, i'm going to re-arrange the diagram objects a bit...

Now it's time to SAVE the design -

I've placed it in a designs folder i have under my user HOME.
After hitting save, you can see where/what is saved/created
2024-07-08 11:31:30 - Design my-new-design saved. (/Users/thatjeffsmith/modeler/my-new-design)

And if we go browse that folder...

That 'dmd' file is what you'll be opening when you want to work with your design again.
So if I close the design and re-open it, we make it pretty easy.
Just use the Recent Designs item on the File menu.

If you can't find your design, just look for the DMD files on your machine.

What I was missing, is that I need to keep all the other files that come with .dmd.
